# How to replace a random value from an array with another one

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So I have this array:

```
TEST = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5], [0,0,1,1,1], [0,1,2,4,5]])
```

And I want to replace a single random number from the array with 6.

With an exact value I would replace him with:

```
TEST[0,0] = 6
```

But since it's a random number that alternates I cannot do that (or maybe I can and just don't know how)

We also have repeated values, so I cannot just pick a value 0 and replace it for 6 since it would replace all the zeros (I think).

So does anyone know how to replace a random number in this specific array? (as an example).

Comment: What is `points`?

Comment: Ops, it's supposed to be "TEST[0:1,0:1] = 6" I will change it, thank you!

Comment: Just like `TEST[0,0] = 6` would replace the value at `[0,0]`, you can pick the row and column indices of the cell to replace and use them as an index into your structure. E.g., `TEST[x,y] = 6`, with `x` and `y` sampled to pick the cell you want to update.

Comment: Why slices instead of just indexes? Is that what you're asking? I'm not sure I understand the question. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're saying you want to do this;

```
import numpy as np
import random

test = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5], [0,0,1,1,1], [0,1,2,4,5]])

n1 = random.randrange(test.shape[0])
n2 = random.randrange(test.shape[1])

test[n1][n2] = 6
```

Comment: Yes! It was as simple as that but I wasn't thinking very clear. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

For a slightly different take, [`numpy.put()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.put.html) allows you to replace and value at the flattened index in an array.

So in the case of:

```
test = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5], [0,0,1,1,1], [0,1,2,4,5]])
```

you could pick a number in the range 0 - 15 and `put()` your value there.

```
test = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5], [0,0,1,1,1], [0,1,2,4,5]])
i = np.random.randint(np.prod(test.shape))
test.put(i, 100)
```

Turning `test` into something like (if i turned out to be 11):

```
array([[  1,   2,   3,   4,   5],
       [  0,   0,   1,   1,   1],
       [  0, 100,   2,   4,   5]])
```